# Ревью библиотеки двусвязных списков

Tags: c, списки, инспекция-кода

Давеча написал зачаток библиотеки для работы с двусвязными списками. Товарищи, дайте критику:

```
// ---------------------------------------------- //
// Doubly linked list implementation by maksspace //
// ---------------------------------------------- //

#ifndef maksspace_list_h
#define maksspace_list_h

typedef struct { void *prev, *next; } node_link_t;

/* this macros through the list starting from the $head while     maintaining the current node in $current */
#define list_foreach(head, current) \
for(typeof(head) current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next)

/* insert $node before $head, and return pointer on new head of list */
void* list_prepend(void* node, void* head) {
    *(node_link_t*)node = (node_link_t){NULL, head};
    return ((node_link_t*)head)->prev = node;
}

/* insert $node after $tail, and return pointer on new tail of list */
void* list_append(void* tail, void* node) {
    *(node_link_t*)node = (node_link_t){tail, NULL};
    return ((node_link_t*)tail)->next = node;
}

/* insert $new_node between $prev and $next, return pointer on $new_node */
void* list_insert(void* new_node, void* prev, void* next) {
    *(node_link_t*)new_node = (node_link_t){prev, next};
    return ((node_link_t*)prev)->next = ((node_link_t*)next)->prev = new_node;
}

/* delete nodes between $from and $to */
void list_nodes_del(void* from, void* to) {
    ((node_link_t*)from)->next = to;
    ((node_link_t*)to)->prev = from;
}

/* -----------------------------------
 * Each node of the list must contain:
 * struct node_name *prev, *next;
 * at the beginning.
 * -----------------------------------
 * Example:

   typedef struct your_node_name {
       struct your_node_name *prev, *next;
       int my_cool_int;
       float my_cool_float;
       ...
       struct { ... } name;
   } me_node_name;
 */

#endif /* maksspace_list_h */
```

Comment: Неудачная попытка изобрести шаблоны там, где их нет. В утиль.

Comment: Почему же сразу в утиль?)

Comment: Для начала, с этой реализацией https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h уже ознакомились?

Comment: @avp да. но api там ужасное

Comment: Дело вкуса, меня не  коробит, хотя самому частенько линейные списки кажутся проще циклических.

Comment: Для запросов на инспекцию кода есть четкие требования. Одно из них — присутствие кода прямо в вопросе. Пожалуйста, прочитайте эти требования и отредактируйте вопрос. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info

Comment: Спасибо, что отредактировали вопрос. У меня есть к вам пара комментариев по документации, оформил пулл-реквестом: https://github.com/maksspace/mylist/pull/1. Жду ответа на комментарии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел ваш https://github.com/maksspace/mylist

`list_insert(void* new, void* prev, void* next)`, возвращающий new, какой-то неочевидный.

Понимаете, если между prev и next есть элементы списка, то они теряются. Я бы подумал над тем, чтобы возвращать исключаемый подсписок (причем с аккуратно модифицированными головой и хвостом) и переименовал этот insert во что-то более отражающее суть дела.

В таком случае аналогичные изменения надо внести и в `void list_nodes_del(void* from, void* to)`.

И мелочь, конечно, но new я бы заменил, поскольку в крестах это ключевое слово.

(за смелость +1)

И еще, а почему, собственно

> Each node of the list must contain:   struct node_name *prev,  *next; 
>   at the beginning.

IMHO Ваш код позволяет вставлять эти структуры связи в любое место структур, образующих список (и также, как и linux/list.h, иметь в структуре много разных связей, т.е. одна структура может входить в несколько разных списков).

Comment: нет, только в начало, потому что https://gist.github.com/maksspace/b074f0530ad37cc60860

Comment: указатель на структуру приводтися к указателю на struct { void *prev, *next; }

Comment: а разве это критично иметь способность размешаться в любом месте целевой структуры?

Comment: Если передавать адрес вашей `node_link_t`, расположенной в середине объемлющей структуры (а не ее адрес), то все будет работать, как и у Линуса (да вы linux/list.h повнимательней посмотрите)

Comment: @maksspace Критично или нет? Если стремиться к общности (т.е. одни и те же данные могут быть в разных списках), то критично.